# Textarea validation

Tags: validation

I'm interested to hear what characters people permit in the various common fields of input forms (barring e-mail...)

For example:

**Textarea/Messages**:  do you allow completely free text, or restrict to alphanumeric and punctuation? I've tried to go the second route, but you always find someone out there that likes using tilde's...

**Full name**: do you allow anything, or do you use a regex?

**Telephone numbers**: numbers only

**Addresses**: alphanumeric, whitespace, hyphens

**City/Town names**: alphabet, hyphens, whitespace

[NB: edited as requested]

Comment: "contact forms" is a bit vague.  Are you talking about Names?  Address?  Phone numbers?  I'm going to have a completely different answer for each.  Perhaps you could refine your question for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no restrictions, provided that:

- the text is not published back to a web page in a way that would permit hijacking/hacking
- the text is not included in a SQL statement in a way that would make it vulnerable to sql injection
- you're reasonably sure that a person is responding and not a bot (captcha, for example)

Answer (score 0):

I've worked at more than one place with these fields in portions of the software I needed to write.  None of them had exactly the same answers.

It really depends on the needs of the people using the software..

Answer (score 0):

I am generally very liberal in what I allow, especially for phone numbers. And if you allow for international phone numbers there are literally hundreds or even thousands of types.

For states I have a drop down list to select from but make sure it is international friendly.

For towns/city I often have a searchable list but allow them to override and enter their own. For street addresses I generally allow almost anything especially when loading from external data which is often full of rubbish addresses in an inconsistent format.